# Angular tutorial: Nodejs and certificate issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, ssl-certificate

I try to set up this [application](https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app):

I followed exactly the procedure in the "Installation" part.

However, when I launch the server (nodejs), I get this error:

```
Angular App Server - listening on port: 3000
Angular App Server - listening on secure port: 8433
Unauthenticated
127.0.0.1 - - [Sun, 08 Sep 2013 10:18:12 GMT] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 739 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_4) AppleWebKit/536.30.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0.5 Safari/536.30.1"
Unauthenticated
Unauthenticated
127.0.0.1 - - [Sun, 08 Sep 2013 10:18:12 GMT] "GET /current-user HTTP/1.1" 200 24 "http://localhost:3000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_4) AppleWebKit/536.30.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0.5 Safari/536.30.1"

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN
    at SecurePair.<anonymous> (tls.js:1350:32)
    at SecurePair.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
    at SecurePair.maybeInitFinished (tls.js:963:10)
    at CleartextStream.read [as _read] (tls.js:463:15)
    at CleartextStream.Readable.read (_stream_readable.js:320:10)
    at EncryptedStream.write [as _write] (tls.js:366:25)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:219:10)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:209:5)
    at EncryptedStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:180:11)
    at write (_stream_readable.js:573:24)
```

Why might this issue occur? How could I fix it?

Perhaps the ReadMe lacks some configuration steps...

Could someone test procedures and put a comment whether the whole works for him, meaning without any errors in logs just after launching the Nodejs server?
It takes about 5 minutes to set it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply turned off my antivirus, and the whole works :)

Have to parameter it to approve some certificates.